# Is not a machine-sized real number

Tags: plotting, complex

I'm trying to plot very simple function. The code is:

```
pN = pB/3;
GF = 1.17*10^-5;
nW = 3 + 3 + 3*3 + 3*3;
GeVtoinversedS = 10^25/6.6;
lwall = 100*Sqrt[2];
c = 3*10^8;
Decaywidth[mN_, U_] = GF^2 mN^5*U^2*nW/(192*Pi^3)*GeVtoinversedS
ldecay[mN_, U_, pB_] = (pN/mN)*c/Decaywidth[mN, U]
θ[η_] = 2*ArcTan[Exp[-η]];
sintheta[η_] = FullSimplify[Sin[θ[η]]]
pTmin[mN_, U_, η_] = lwall/(ldecay[mN, U, 1])*sintheta[η]
pTmin[1, 10^U, 1]
LogLogPlot[pTmin[1, 10^U, 1], {U, -10, -3}]
```

However, the output is

> ```
> LogLogPlot::plln: Limiting value I π+log(10) in
> {Charting`Private`pvar$2920,I π+log(10),I π+log(10)} is not a
> machine-sized real number.
> ```

What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
pN = pB/3;
GF = 1.17*10^-5;
nW = 3 + 3 + 3*3 + 3*3;
GeVtoinversedS = 10^25/6.6;
lwall = 100*Sqrt[2];
c = 3*10^8;

Decaywidth[mN_, U_] = GF^2 mN^5*U^2*nW/(192*Pi^3)*GeVtoinversedS;

ldecay[mN_, U_, pB_] = (pN/mN)*c/Decaywidth[mN, U];

θ[η_] = 2*ArcTan[Exp[-η]];

sintheta[η_] = FullSimplify[Sin[θ[η]]];

pTmin[mN_, U_, η_] = lwall/(ldecay[mN, U, 1])*sintheta[η];
```

You cannot use a [`LogLogPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LogLogPlot.html) since the x-axis ranges over negative values whose [`Log`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Log.html) is complex. Note

```
Log[-5]

(* I π + Log[5] *)
```

Use [`LogPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LogPlot.html)

```
LogPlot[pTmin[1, 10^U, 1], {U, -10, -3}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! My mistake was so simple...

Answer (score 2):

Since your `U` values are negative, `Log[U]` is complex, and this is a problem for the ticks. You probably wanted to do:

```
LogLogPlot[pTmin[1,U,1], {U, 10^-10, 10^-3}]
```

[image]

or you could use [`LogPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LogPlot) as suggested by @BobHanlon.